# google app engine server reports error but on local server the code works fine

Tags: java, http, google-app-engine, url

```
String sourceUrlString="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address="+searchWord+"&sensor=true";//searchWord-parameter to be passed
Source source=new Source(new URL(sourceUrlString));

Element alpha=source.getFirstElement("location");
String beta[]=new String[100];

String lat=alpha.getContent().getFirstElement("lat").getContent().toString();
String lng=alpha.getContent().getFirstElement("lng").getContent().toString();
```

THE error pointed out by google app engine is in the above bold statements it says null pointer exception but on local server it returns the value and the code works fine.

wat are the possible solution to the above problem?and as of what i have come to conclusion is google app engine does not support Http request .is it true?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use URL Fetch service to issue HTTP requests and receive responses:
One example:
import urllib2

url = "http://www.google.com/"
try:
  result = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  doSomethingWithResult(result)
except urllib2.URLError, e:
  handleError(e)

Comment: I think the question is about java.

Comment: thank you it worked i guess i was concentrating on just how to extract data from the xml file rather than trying other options............